# Crystal Reports C# formula returning false only

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports-xi

I have created one crystal report where I want to write a formula.

```
my formula:
IF {Sp_Get_DailyReport;1.Job_Status} = 'Workshop' 
THEN {Sp_Get_DailyReport;1.Department_Name}
```

but, this formula doesn't returning a value.
i have edited my formula, now i'm getting as 'false' instead of Dept-name.

```
stringvar text := "";
IF {Sp_Get_DailyReport;1.Job_Status} = "Workshop" 
THEN text = "{Sp_Get_DailyReport;1.Department_Name}"
```

In ReportFooter i have created one column for workshop where i want to display department name n unit name whose units are in workshop and i'm placing this formula field in ReportFooter where its returns only one value,
instead of each condition where its true &
why its returning 'false' i dont know, instead of dept name.
I want to select all those records whose jobstatus is workshop n display it in the reprotfooter.
Can anyone please help me...

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure this is c#? It almost looks like Delphi

Answer (score 0):

TROUBLE SHOOT

IF {Sp_Get_DailyReport;1.Job_Status} = "Workshop" 
THEN {Sp_Get_DailyReport;1.Department_Name}
ELSE
{Sp_Get_DailyReport;1.Job_Status}

This function will return the value of the Job_Staus if the Job_Status value is anything BUT "Workshop"

Are you sure the Job_Status value contains "Workshop" 
Check for Spaces as Well  could try trimming Job_Status